# how to remove comma using CSS if already added comma in text

Tags: css

how to remove comma with using CSS

```
<ul id="taglist">
  <li>apple,</li>
  <li>orange,</li>
  <li>banana,</li>
</ul>
```

i can add like this

```
#taglist li:after {
  content: ", ";
}
```

but i want to remove if already add comma in text, tell me if anyone know that trick thank you.

Comment: CSS cannot detect content...it only styles what is there, You need Javascript...or just edit the HTML.

Comment: @Paulie_D That's true... but, it could be possible to achieve that with pure CSS if we had a web font providing white-space rather than comma `,`, so we could use [`unicode-range`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-fonts/#unicode-range-desc) to apply that font for a specific codepoint. That's a hammer to break nuts though.

Comment: @HashemQolami That's like dropping an extinction-level asteroid on a nut to crack it.

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to target the content of an element using CSS alone. Your only options are to either edit your HTML, use JavaScript to perform some string manipulation or if you're using a server-side language then use that to perform the string manipulation.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. You should try removing with with PHP instead before your document is rendered.

Place your HTML into a variable called content and use this command

```
<?php
$content = str_replace(",","",$content);
echo $content;
?>
```

Comment: You are correct in your approach but there is no indication in the question that PHP is being used.